# How to check if a Checkbox is checked?

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have two check boxes,and I want to set tag as per its selection or check status,so can any one tell me how to set tags in my application,the following is my code tell me my mistakes,..

```
    if(matchcheck.isChecked())//checked then
    {
        matchcheck.setTag("N1");//set No 1..
    }
    else
    {
        matchcheck.setTag("Y1");//set yes 1
    }

    if(newsletter.isChecked())
    {
        newsletter.setTag("N2");//set no 2
    }
    else
    {
        newsletter.setTag("Y2");//set yes 2
    }
```

Comment: what's TAG for you ?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking...

Comment: in my tag i stored values n1 y1 so on

Comment: Are these values **mutually exclusive** (Yes1/No1 and Yes2/No2)? If so, use RadioButtons (two RadioGroups with 2 RadioButtons each), instead of CheckBoxes.

Comment: but what if i want to use checkbox

Comment: If your question is how to set tags, your doing it correctly (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29). But if your asking why tag is not setted with your code logic, please change your question to be more explicit asking how to check if a Checkbox is checked.

Comment: @HugoGresse my problem is I want to settag Y1 means Yes1 if first checkbox is checked othervise I want to settag N1 No1..and same as for next checkbox..now u got it what I am asking?

Comment: Oh, well, maybe I understood what you mean. You can use a **bitmask** to manage your CheckBoxes. `00` for none checked, `01` if the second is checked, `10` if the first one is checked, `11` if both are checked.

Comment: @DerGolem yeah somethink like that..can you help me with this

Comment: It's a bit long. Not complicated, just long. In synthesis, on a CheckBox check, you set or unset its bit in a shared int variable. Then you check the int against a mask (1 = 01, 2 = 10, in your case), to reveal if that bit is active (1) or not (0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just setting the opposite of what you want.

```
    if(matchcheck.isChecked())//checked then
    {
        matchcheck.setTag("Y1");//set yes 1
    }
    else
    {
        matchcheck.setTag("N1");//set No 1
    }

    if(newsletter.isChecked())
    {
        newsletter.setTag("Y2");//set yes 2
    }
    else
    {
        newsletter.setTag("N2");//set no 2
    }
```

Should be your code.

But anyway, consider using RadioButtons and giving them the look and feel you want. It will be easier, they are intended for these kind of situations.

Comment: by default it was going in else part that is why i interchange..otherwise it was same as you said..any way thanks for answer